# Stream to stream conversion with icecast

Tags: mp3, streaming, format-conversion, icecast

Currently I am using icecast to relay any stream, but i want my output steam in mp3 format whatever is input stream.

Like if input relaying stream is mp4 I want my icecast to give just mp3 format of that stream.

How it is possible? or how i can do this?
Any tool for stream to stream conversion or making icecast to give only mp3 output.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Icecast itself only broadcasts streams, it won't touch the content of a stream.

What you want is mostly referred to as *transcoding* and is accomplished by additional software.

For audio streaming [we](http://icecast.org) recommend to use Vorbis or Opus as the codec. Generally we don't recommend using MP3 as the stream codec, as it's quality is low and there are still some patent issues.

When it comes to software capable of transcoding you might want to evaluate:

- liquidsoap
- mpd
- vlc
- gst-launch